# Difference in behaviour of glossaries in article and beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting, glossaries, italic, article

I'm using `glossaries-extra` in a `beamer`-document to typeset acronyms and a glossary. As it is good practice in german texts to italize english technical terms I wanted to do so with some acronyms, too.

The desired output is as the following - disregarding the wrong linebreak with german words as I haven't set any options to keep the MWE short-ish. [image: Desired output]

To test an error I got compiling my `beamer`-source I created an `article`-document on sharelatex. Surprisingly I encountered no problemes at all.

I used the same preamble, cut the `beamer`-related stuff - still got the desired result. Switching the `documentclass` on sharelatex to `beamer` got me the same errors as in my project.

Some of the errors are:

- `! Undefined control sequence.
  \in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@
                                ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...`
- `Illegal parameter number in definition of \glo@IAM@first.
  <to be read again>`

I have no clue, why this problem occurs. Maybe someone out there has an idea - otherwise I just cut the `\textit` out of the definition of these two acronyms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,nopostdot,shortcuts=all,nonumberlist,xindy]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{IAM}{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={IAM},
    description={\textit{immobilized artificial membrane}, \glsseeformat[Glossar:]{IAM-gls}{}},
    first={\textit{immobilized artificial membrane} (IAM)\glsadd{IAM-gls}},
    plural={IAMs}
}
\newglossaryentry{FAC}{
    type=\acronymtype,
    name={FAC},
    description={\textit{frontal affinity chromatography}, \glsseeformat[Glossar:]{FAC-gls}{}},
    first={\textit{frontal affinity chromatography} (FAC)\glsadd{FAC-gls}},
    plural={FACs}
}

\newglossaryentry{IAM-gls}{%
    name={IAM},
    description={Eine \gls{IAM} ist ein System, welches eine feste Membran imitiert. Hergestellt wird sie durch kovalente Bindung von membranbildenden Lipiden in einen amorphen Siliciumdioxid-Substrat. \Glspl{IAM} werden erfolgreich genutzt, um Stofftransporte durch Zellmembranen hervorzusagen; und um Membranproteine aufzureinigen und wiederherzustellen. Die typische Größe einer \gls{IAM} besträgt \SI{54}{\angstrom} mal \SI{54}{\angstrom} mit einer durchschnittlich \SI{30}{\angstrom} dicken Schicht Wasser, welche die Oberfläche solvatisiert.}
}
\newglossaryentry{FAC-gls}{%
    name={FAC},
    description={In einem Lauf können die Bindungskonstanten K\textsubscript{d} aller aktiven, in Sub-Mikrogramm-Mengen vorliegenden Verbindungen einer Ligandenbibliothek bestimmt werden. Dazu wird das Ligandengemisch kontinuierlich auf eine Säule mit immobilisiertem Rezeptor gegeben und das Eluat Elektrospray-massenspektrometrisch analysiert. Aus dem erhaltenen Affinitätschromatogramm können die Durchbruchvolumina der einzelnen Verbindungen abgelesen und daraus die K\textsubscript{d}-Werte berechnet werden.}
}

\begin{document}

\Gls{IAM} is a nice thing. One can use the \gls{IAM} for \gls{FAC}, because \glspl{FAC} are good.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\glsresetall
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error occurs on TL 2015, Linux, latest state before freeze as well. A `\protect\textit` cures this problem, but it runs into another issue afterwards with `\beamer@cramped`

Comment: Do you get the desired output with `article`?

Comment: Well, it compiles with `article`, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much shorter example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,first={\textit{sample}},
  description={an example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\gls{sample}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printglossary
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that `\textit` isn't a robust command with `beamer` whereas it is with `article`. By default the value of the `first` key is [expanded by `\newglossaryentry`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:expansion) and now that `\textit` is no longer robust this expansion breaks.

The simplest solution is to suppress this expansion:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\glsnoexpandfields

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name=sample,first={\textit{sample}},
  description={an example}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\gls{sample}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printglossary
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Finally, thanks a lot! I searched the interwebz for a couple of days and didn't find any solution for this problem. Thanks a lot!